# EditText in Google Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create the **EditText** which allow **Numeric Values**, **Comma**  and **Delete** and other values are ignore.

So How I can achieve this by programming code ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want people to be able to input the following? Because as far as I know, all of them are valid commands in edittext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved same thing using follwing code, hope you will also find help from it.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(controller);


@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(s.trim.length() > 0)
            {
                 int start = s.toString().length() - 1;
                 int a = (int) s.charAt(start);
                 if (!(a >= 48 && a <= 57 || a == 44))
                    s = s.delete(start, start + 1);
            }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To restrict what characters can be typed into an android EditText, you must set them in the android:digits XML attribute. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits . Make sure to also validate user input before putting it into storage.

Comment: Mao It allow to enter only digit. But I allow to enter **Digits**, **Comma**, **Delete** and **Back Space**.

Comment: Well, the only one that will cause you trouble is the Comma. Why is the comma necessary, do you want to put values like "100,000"? If all you want is for the user to input numbers, you can set the android:numeric attribute to true. Otherwise, you may have to override the KeyListener.

Comment: @Mao I want to take **Mobile Numbers** separated by **Comma**

Comment: In that case, either override KeyListener or allow the user to input anything but validate input when they submit. The second choice would be easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

just simple ,

you want to create a text-field like that you can enter the new string must have some grammar that you want to allow.

i have some email validation grammar that can help you.

string = "/alphabetics/number/special-character" ;

and another is

user-entered-string = " ";

just compare user-entered-string's lexems and you defined grammar.