# How can I use the comma separator within EditText when the inputType attribute is set to 'number'?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I want to create an EditText array where only number input is allowed. I would like to use a comma to separate the digits. I have created the EditText array with the following code and the keyboard behavior has changed, but nothing happens when I press the comma key.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
      
    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">      
                <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="max."
                android:gravity="center"
                android:ems="4"
                android:id="@+id/editText"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547590/edittext-in-google-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this input type:

```
InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
```

Or in xml:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```